# Remap symbols in Visual Studio (like in AutoHotkey)

Tags: visual-studio

I want to add some custom keyboard bindings to use with Visual Studio only. For instance, I'm thinking about using a single key to type `::` for a C++ code.
Code snippets wouldn't improve the ergonomics - to insert it, at least I'll have to press "Tab" twice. The shortcut settings (Options -> Environment -> Keyboard) only provide settings for the predefined actions.
So the only way I see is to use AutoHotkey scripts (or any similar external tool). But maybe, Visual Studio already has got a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom VS command with my [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) extension and then assign a shortcut to it in Keyboard options.